# Employee absences in calendar (vlookup?)

Tags: excel, calendar

I am struggling with a case related to employee absences being visually structured in Excel.

I managed to extract the data via SQL into Excel and have a list like the following:
[image]

I need an overview like the following and do not find a formula which can solve this case:
[image]

The first picture resembles an extract of a huge list, the primary key is "Employee", which is necessary to determine the correct place in the second picture, the visual overview in the calendar.

Which formula do I need to enter in these cells (col[G] to col[XXX]) so that the correct "V" will be placed under the right data.

So far I figured out how Excel checks the date "from" and "to" and places the "V" accordningly but row by row and not adjusted to one employee in total (like I would like to have it in the screenshot).

formula (it only checks whether the date is in between):

```
=IF(AND(F$1<=$C2,F$1>=$B2),"V","")
```

Do you think it's easier to solve this via VBA? I would love to have the best performance for that because the dataset is huge, I thought that a formula in this case would be faster.

Vlookup does not fit in the case, because it only matches the first entry found, but maybe something similar?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Looks like you should fire employee 1

Comment: thanks @BigBen, I tried that too, but is there a combination of other functions I must take into consideration? Only COUNTIFS will not be enough, or does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INDEX` and `AGGREGATE` to return the type (V, S, etc.) when the date header falls between `DATE_from` and `DATE_to`, for each employee. Wrap this in `IFEFROR` to return a blank string if no match is found.

For example:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$10000,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$9999)/(($A$2:$A$10000=$E3)*($B$2:$B10000<=F$1)*($C$2:$C$10000>=F$1)),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: what about referencing to the Absence Type, as shown in my first Screenshot. How do I use those entries instead of 'V' all the time the IF statement is TRUE? The employee could be sick ('S') as well.

Comment: do i have to use a combination of the employee ID, the date from and date to, to determine/match the unique absence type?

Comment: Are "V" and "S" the only options?